# Can we return array from database query using rest API in nodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, rest

I have code in nodejs:

```
app.post("/getServerDetails", function(req, res){
    var id = req.body.id;
    if (con == null)
        con = db.openCon(con);
    Promise.all([
        new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            con.query("select serverName from servers where id = ?", [id], function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    resolve(null);
                    res.status(200).json({success: 0});
                }
                resolve(result);
            });
        })
    ])
    .then((results)=>{
        res.status(200).json(results[0]);
    });

});
```

I have get ouput in results[0]:

> Part-I : [ RowDataPacket { serverName: 'server1' },   RowDataPacket {
>   serverName: 'server2' },   RowDataPacket { serverName: 'server3' },
>   RowDataPacket { serverName: 'server4' },   RowDataPacket { serverName:
>   'server5' } ]

Actually, my code is working perfectly but I need array like this:

> Part-II : [server1, server2, server3, server4, server5]

So, Guys can I have this output like Part-II instead of Part-I. Actually I didn't understand how I achieve this. Your help is very appreciable to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> RowDataPacket is show that object is instance of  RowDataPacket class. feel
>   free to treat result as a normal object.
>
> mysql api always return rows/results {array} so you can simply get your result from
>   result[0]

```
enter code here
```

also you can skip messing of callbacks and promises in your code. take an example

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var mysql = require('mysql')

var connection = mysql.createConnection({ ... })

Promise.promisify(connection.query, connection)('SELECT 1').then(function (rows) {
  console.log('got rows!')
  console.dir(rows)
  connection.end()
})
```

ref. https://www.bountysource.com/issues/5457730-using-node-mysql-with-promises